# Software to create SF2 soundfonts

Tags: windows, gratis, music-production

Since the day I found [MuseScore](https://musescore.org/) I play keyboard more often again. I now found out that MuseScore can play different sounds using SF2 soundfonts. While I was downloading some soundfonts from the web, I am wondering how those files are created.

I am looking for

- a SF2 soundfont creation program
- for Windows 7 or 10
- that is gratis

I assume it would take normal audio (WAV files or MP3) as input, I define the recorded frequency and the program calculates other frequencies. For the moment this is just a guess, since I'm not familiar with the process. Any process is fine for me.

Comment: Have you seen https://musescore.org/node/13734 for a non-exclusive list of editors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the list](https://musescore.org/node/13734) suggested by [@Steve Barnes](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/142/steve-barnes) I picked [Polyphone](http://polyphone-soundfonts.com/en/) because their website looked so well made.

It fulfills the requirements:

- works on Windows (tested on Windows 7)
- creates SF2 sound fonts
- is gratis ([GPL](http://polyphone-soundfonts.com/en/license))
- imports WAV files that can e.g. be recorded with Audacity

To me, that program was **super intuitive and very stable**. I loaded an existing sound font to see what a final result looks like and after that I immediately created my own sound font without any issue (except perhaps that my singing is not perfect and the tones should be adjusted in pitch a bit).

Really awesome stuff that you get for free nowadays. Worth a donation.